# zsh: get out of sh/ksh emulation for paramter expansion

Tags: zsh

I have some library code that *might* run under `zsh` (`ZSH_VERSION` set), but the caller's `zsh` *might* be in `sh` / `ksh` emulation mode. I need a zsh parameter expansion (list all variables, for example), so I tried to use `emulate zsh -c ...`:

```
export code='print -rl -- ${(k)parameters}'
zsh --emulate  sh -c 'emulate zsh -c "$code"'  # nothing
zsh --emulate ksh -c 'emulate zsh -c "$code"'  # nothing
zsh --emulate zsh -c 'emulate zsh -c "$code"'  # useless, but works
# emulate -[LR] zsh make no difference
```

So... once in `sh` / `ksh` emulation, I can't get out of it temporarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get out of (k)sh emulation. The `emulate` builtin just sets a number of options: it's a shortcut for a very long, zsh-version-dependent `setopt` command, plus some setup to get the desired scope.

Starting zsh with the `--emulate` option does a little more than just set some options. The [manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Invocation.html#Invocation-2) is unfortunately vague about this:

> Note that certain extra steps are taken to ensure a smooth emulation when this option is used compared with the emulate command within the shell: for example, variables that conflict with POSIX usage such as path are not defined within the shell.

One of the things that doesn't happen with `--emulate  sh` or `--emulate ksh` is loading [modules](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Zsh-Modules) such as [`zsh/parameter`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module) which provides `$parameters`. If you need that even when zsh was started in an emulation mode, you need to load it explicitly. Contrast:

```
$ zsh --emulate sh -c 'emulate zsh -c "echo \${(k)modules}"'
$ zsh --emulate sh -c 'zmodload zsh/parameter; emulate zsh -c "echo \${(k)modules}"'
zsh/parameter zsh/main zsh/rlimits
```

Therefore:

```
$ export code='zmodload zsh/parameter; print -rl -- ${(k)parameters}'
$ zsh --emulate  sh -c 'emulate zsh -c "$code"'
galiases
…
EGID
```